# Files missing in ZFS pool after power outage, only newly written files appear

Tags: 18.04, raid, zfs

After an unexpected power outage in my town early this morning, my wife tells me that some recorded TV shows she wanted to watch on Plex are not playing.  After some investigation, I am seeing that only directories written to the ZFS volume after the outage are appearing - all previous files seem "missing".  After the power came back on, my machine booted back up and Plex happily continued recording its scheduled shows to the ZFS volume.  Unfortunately, only those recently written files are accessible.

On a HP Gen8 Microserver, I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on an SSD (along with my applications) and have a ZFS pool of 3x8TB drives in a raidz1 array for the storage of all my media.  I do have an off-site backup of everything that is important (photos and important documents).

When I look at "zpool status", it appears everything is functioning correctly.

```
zpool status
  pool: pool1
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 23h29m with 0 errors on Sun Jan 12 23:53:02 2020
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    pool1       ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
```

It also seems to be displaying that the data is still exists in some way, as "zpool status" shows the pool size free space I expect.

```
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
pool1  21.8T  19.5T  2.27T         -     9%    89%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

I have the ZFS pool1 mounted to /mnt/pool1.  I used to be able to "df -h" and see the volume and its size and usage, but now it has disappeared from there as well:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sdd1       220G   68G  141G  33% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop7      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop2      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
/dev/loop10      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop5       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/loop3       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/375
/dev/loop6      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/plexmediaserver/46
/dev/loop0       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1288
/dev/loop9       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop4      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop11      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/loop8      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop13     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/73
/dev/loop12      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop15     157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/91
/dev/loop16     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/111
/dev/loop19      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop17     4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/536
/dev/loop18     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop14     100M  100M     0 100% /snap/plexmediaserver/48
tmpfs           1.6G   28K  1.6G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

My Google-fu seems weak at the moment and can't seem to find the right information to lead me in the right direction to recover this.  Any help to steer me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!  Admittedly I was smart enough to set up ZFS and set up off-site backup for my important data, but my skills are weak when it comes to troubleshooting this in CLI.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see the ZFS pool with `df` it isn't mounted and Plex is writing your new episodes to your root filesystem instead.

Try: `zfs mount -a`

..and check `df` again.

If this works your recently added files will seem to disappear because your mounted ZFS pool will mask the files on the root filesystem.   You can move them to a temporary directory before mounting your pool, then copy them back to your ZFS pool.

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was.  I tried "mount -a", but failed to remember that it needed to be "zfs mount -a" since I am dealing with the zfs volume.  Good information to know if this should happen again!